# property of non-object error, while it is an object

Tags: php

When I want to go over my data and print some data from the database I get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in XYZ on line 76
```

Now this line 76:

```
printf('name": "%s",', $title2->title);
```

More specifically the part around line 76 is:

```
            $rtitle = "SELECT title FROM table WHERE genre='$category'";
        $ptitles = mysqli_query($connection,$rtitle) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
            while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles));
            printf('name": "%s",', $title2->title);
```

I am not entirely sure why this error occurs. Apparently it is because $title2->title is not object, however, using a similar function above works ok. So not entirely sure what goes wrong here. Help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP error occurs on the line:

```
printf('name": "%s",', $title2->title);
```

but your problem is in your `while` statement:

```
while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles));
```

The way you have placed the `;` means you are just looping without any code inside the loop.

Try

```
while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles))
   printf('name": "%s",', $title2->title); // only code inside loop
```

or

```
while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles)) {
   printf('name": "%s",', $title2->title);
   // ... any further code you want inside your loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are experiencing is because you don't enter the loop and you end it with  a semicolon, so your object might have another level  `0`

```
while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles));
printf('name": "%s",', $title2->0->title);
```

Otherwise you can use the loop

```
while ($title2 = mysqli_fetch_object($ptitles))
{
    printf('name": "%s",', $title2->title);
}
```